# Error with DNN module

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have a comments module in my DNN site. I have installed that module on my site successfully but I am not able to work with it. It shows these errors.

1. Uncaught ReferenceError: ko is not defined
2. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'fromJS' of undefined
3. GET`http://localhost:1726/resources/shared/scripts/jquery/jquery.min.map` 404 (Not Found)
4. GET `http://localhost:1726/jquery.min.map` 404 (Not Found)

But I have defined ko in my JavaScript code:

```
function Comment(data) {    
    var self = this;    
    self.CommentId = ko.observable();    
    self.CommentText = ko.observable();    
    self.ModuleId = ko.observable();    
    self.PortalId = ko.observable();    
    self.updateFromJS = function (data) {    
        if (data != null && data != undefined)
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
    };   
    self.updateFromJS(data);    
};
```

Comment: what is the name of the module ??

Comment: My module name is MyComments

Comment: are you building this module ?

Comment: I don't think you need any external library because DNN have jquery included in DNN